# Undefined response from login request after upgrading from Http (ng2) to HttpClient (ng6)

Tags: javascript, angular, basic-authentication, angular-httpclient

I can't seem to access the response to my login request after upgrading from Angular's `Http` to `HttpClient`. This is the working code for Http:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/login', '', {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
               .map((response: Response) => {
                 if (response.status === 200) {
                   localStorage.setItem('setCookie', resHeaders.get("Set-Header"));
                   window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=api&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://" + document.location.host + "/%23/token//%3F";
                   return true;
                 } 
                 else {
                   return false;
                 }
               });
  }
```

This is the code I use for HttpClient:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let httpHeaders : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      .set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password))
      .set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/login', '', {headers: httpHeaders, withCredentials: true})
      .pipe(
        map(res => {  // res: undefined
          if (res) {
            console.log("res: " + res);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Didn't get any response");
          }
        })
      )
  }
```

Output from the `HttpClient` code is `Didn't get any response`. [HttpClient Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) uses pipe like in my code above, but `res` is also undefined if I just use `.map` like I do with `Http`. I have examined the actual requests and responses in Chrome, and they are identical to the working code using `Http`. So I know that the problem is that I'm doing something wrong when trying to access the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all that was missing is that I needed to add `observe: 'response'` to the request options, like so:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let httpHeaders : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      .set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password))
      .set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/login', '', {headers: httpHeaders, withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(res => {  // res: [object Object]
          if (res) {
            console.log("res: " + res);
          }
          else {
            console.log("Didn't get any response");
          }
        })
      )
  }
```

This allows me to access the response headers that I need, as per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the subscribefunction now to access your Responseobject.

Notice that you will return a subscribtion Object now.
Try something like this:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/login', '', {headers: httpHeaders, withCredentials: true})
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log("res: " + res);
                },
    error => {
    console.log("error" + error);
    }
```

);

Comment: While your answer is correct, it wasn't the issue in my case. I was already subscribing to the response in the component. I posted an answer with the solution in case you're interested.